# Google Fonts showing up bold with no bold property

Tags: html, email, outlook, google-font-api

I have an email coming out of Salesforce and into an Outlook 365 client.

HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
        }

       <p>
            <h4>Thanks for reaching out to</h4>
       </p>
```

It keeps outputting as bold, I checked the source of the email received in outlook and no additional bold styling has been applied during the outbound process.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `<h4>` is displayed as bold.